# How to vertically align website logo and header with navbar

Tags: html, css, position, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to vertically align the navbar with my website logo and header, but whenever I try to use `display: inline-block;` and `vertical-align: middle;` on the , , and  tags (which are all in the same div on the top of my website), the navbar goes from horizontal to vertical which is not what I want. I'm also using Bootstrap 4.

Here's my html:

```
<div id="home">
    <div class="page-header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="images/test-logo.png">
                    <h1>Rigid Signs</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here's my CSS:

```
    #home {
    background: url('../images/workshop-testphoto.jpg') no-repeat center / cover;
    height: 844px;
}

.page-header {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    postion: fixed;/*not working*/
    padding: 11px 0;
}

.page-header img, .page-header h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.page-header img {
    width: 88px;
}

.page-header h1 {
    font-size: 32px;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 11px;
}

.page-header .nav {
    float: right;
}

.page-header .nav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}
```

I'm not very good with bootstrap 4, but if anyone knows how I could use bootstrap 4 to also achieve my goal of vertically aligning all elements in my navbar, that would be great aswell

Comment: Why don't you use [navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) in place of [page header](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#page-header)?

Comment: @Shiva like I said, I'm not that good with bootstrap.... but thank you for showing me that!I'm going to change my code and use navbar instead of page-header

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, bootstrap grid have "float" styling in it. so col-md-4 and col-md-8 will have float left. so, use inline-block instead of float, and give vertical-align middle for both div. using the current html you're showing, it will be

```
.row {
    font-size: 0; /*to remove blank space between two inline-block element*/
}

.col-md-4, .col-md-8 {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle
}
```

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work:( it makes the logo huge and puts the h1 under it, while the navbar stays in the same place at the top of the div...